# Sort grouped by dataframe according to the count values of groups

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have grouped by and sorted the values within group of dataframe by applying below 2 queries:

```
df = df.groupby(['table_name','query_param_clean2']).size().to_frame('count').reset_index()

df = df.sort_values(['table_name','count'],ascending=False).groupby('table_name').apply(lambda x: x)
```

The dataframe looks like this now :

```
table_name           query_param_clean2           count
A                       query4                    24
A                       query1                    16
A                       query2                    8
B                       query5                    56
B                       query6                    50
C                       query3                    100
D                       query1                    13
D                       query4                    12
D                       query2                    10
D                       query8                    1
```

Here, I have dataframe properly grouped up and sorted according to the count with in the group. Now, I want to do the sorting between groups.

For example: C under table_name has first row with highest value of 100, so C should be the top group in the output, after C , B should be there because the first row of B has the second largest value of 56 after 100.

The output dataframe should look like below.

What can i add in my second line of code or add something else to get data in below form.

```
table_name           query_param_clean2           count
C                       query3                    100
B                       query5                    56
B                       query6                    50
A                       query4                    24
A                       query1                    16
A                       query2                    8
D                       query1                    13
D                       query4                    12
D                       query2                    10
D                       query8                    1
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that comes to my mind is to first get a list of `table_name` sorted by the highest count of the top record. Then sort your `df` in order of this list.

```
first = df.sort_values(['table_name','count'],ascending=False).groupby('table_name').first()
ordered = first.sort_values(['count'], ascending=False)
orderedNameList = ordered['table_name'].tolist()
df = df.sort_values(['table_name'],ascending=orderedNameList)
```

My syntax is probably not correct but maybe a similar idea to this would work.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way. Here I explicitly calculate an `order` column based on the max of each `table_name`, order by this column, then drop it.

```
lst = df.groupby('table_name', as_index=False)['count'].max().\
         sort_values('count', ascending=False)['table_name'].tolist()

df['order'] = df['table_name'].map({j: i for i, j in enumerate(lst)})

df = df.sort_values('order').drop('order', 1)

#   table_name query_param_clean2  count
# 5          C             query3    100
# 3          B             query5     56
# 4          B             query6     50
# 0          A             query4     24
# 1          A             query1     16
# 2          A             query2      8
# 6          D             query1     13
# 7          D             query4     12
# 8          D             query2     10
# 9          D             query8      1
```